# In a MVC architecture, can the `View` access the model?

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have to build a website in MVC pattern.

I have a "showuser.jsp" view, I can access the Model (DAO) in order to get all the users,

or my controller should pass this information to my view?

Comment: Which framework you are using ?  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: _my controller should pass this information to my view_ yes it should, that's the purpose of MVC. Your view should know only about Controller, it should co-ordinate with models and others.

Comment: @Santosh Tagged it, `Hibernate`.

Comment: It is possible, but then what's the meaning of the MVC pattern? none.

Comment: @user1798362, hibernate is the ORM tool. In most probability it will be abstracted by `Service`. I was expecting some MVC framework like struts or spring-mvc. BTW please look at my answers to your query.

Comment: @user1798362 wow ... you somehow managed to get only **wrong answers**. All of them. To learn about information flow in MVC architecture you should start by a quick look [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller#Component_interactions) and then read the [original definition](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html), followed by [more up-to-date explanation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) by Martin Fowler. *The brief version: views should have direct access to model layer, without intervention from controllers.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical sequence of MVC flow is as follows

1. `User` sends a page view request
2. `Controller` receives the request
3. `Controller` queries the `Model` for the data
4. `Model`returns the data (*List of users in your case*)
5. `Controller` passes this data to the selected `View` (`showuser.jsp`) (*generally as request/session attribute*)
6. The `View` is rendered and returned to the user.

This is nicely depicted in the following image:

[image]

I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Great answer! BUT: If user sends request to the view, how can the controller recieve it?

Comment: You always request a `View` but just that, the request URL is mapped to the `Controller` hence it always receives the request first. `Controller` _knows_ which view to send to the client. So, once it has  got the data from the model, it sets the data and forwards the request to the configured `View`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally controller fills model for the view (JSP).

You controller should call DAO (even better if you have Service layer where all the business logic is implemented. Then controller calls the Service which may have one or mode DAO). And store the info in model to be represented on the jsp.

Comment: How should the info passed from the controller to the view?

Comment: Just include Model parameter in the controller's method and store the data in the model.

Answer (score 0):

This should be seamless.  The view should not be aware of the model as such but it should be passed through the controller, a common technique in Spring MVC would be to pass a hibernate object through the controller which would then get converted to JSON.

The View would then render this JSON object and parse it appropriately.  In your example your controller could pass to the view a list of User objects which you could then parse if it was an array of JSON objects.

Your view should call a controller, which would return the response from either the DAO or Service layer (depending on your business logic requirements).

Answer (score 0):

In the MVC pattern the `model` and `view` should no be aware of each other.  The `model` and `view` are  bound together by a `controller`.  So the `controller` should pass the `model` to the `view`.

To put it rather simply in code:

```
class View{}

class Model{}

class Controller{
    View view = new View();
    Model model = new Model();

    public void controllerMethod(){
        //pass model to view
    }
}
```